# How to match only the titles between <h></h> tags, without returning the tags themselves, using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, html-parsing, regex-lookarounds, non-greedy

I want to match the titles of `h1` to `h6` in an HTML file, without returning the `h` tags themselves, using regular expressions.

Consider the following piece of an HTML file.
I want to match "Welcome to my Homepage", "SQL", "RegEx", but not "This is not a valid HTML" (which is surrounded by a pair of unmatched tags).

```
<body>
  <H1>Welcome to my Homepage</H1>
  Content is divided into two sections:<br/>
  <h2>SQL</h2>
  Information about SQL.
  <h2>RegEx</h2>
  Information about Regular Expressions.
  <h3>This is not a valid HTML</h4>
</body>
```

I use [`(?<=<[hH]([1-6])>).*?(?=<\/[hH]\1>)` at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mFt85G/1). However, it also mathes the numbers `1`, `2` in the tags `<H1>` and `<h2>`.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it also matches the numbers `1`, `2` in the tags `<H1>` and `<h2>`.

Not really. The match itself captures only the content. The number comes from the capturing group in your lookbehind. You can just ignore that.